# Java: название переменных на русском языке

Tags: java

Корректно ли Java будет воспринимать этот программный код на всех ОС:

```
int число = 0;
String строка = "1";
System.out.println("Результат = " + String.valueOf(число + Integer.parseInt(строка) + 1));
```

Действительно ли можно называть любую переменную на русском языке??

Я просто хочу убедиться, что скомпилировать мой файл `Main.java` с этим кодом удастся на любой Java-машине.

Comment: @post_zeew, тогда почему у меня программа скомпилировалась?

Comment: Вы это из праздного интереса спрашиваете? Или хотите это на практике использовать?

Comment: @post_zeew, на практике.

Comment: Работать это будет, но я все равно Вам не советую, ибо моветон.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если конкретная реализация соответствует официальной спецификации, то будет воспринимать правильно, см. спецификацию:
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8
Но для "взрослого" программирования это очень-очень плохая практика. Далеко не все программисты, которым, возможно, придется читать ваш код, обязаны знать русский. Так что я бы крайне не советовал привыкать. Используйте латинский алфавит и имена идентификаторов на основе английских слов, чтобы смысл программы был легко понятен каждому независимо от национальности.